# Assign modulator LFO to parameter in Logic pro x

Tags: logic-pro, modulation

I am trying to assign the midi LFO in Logic pro x to the volume in a midi instrument (EXS24). I set the LFO "to" to an empty channel, but when I right-click the volume in my instrument I don't get the option to learn the LFO.

I am a total noob. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I've never used Logic Pro, but what you're describing is a tremolo. Is there not a tremolo effect on the EXS24?

Comment: I believe the EXS24 has its own lfos and modulators within it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the channel effects for your sound, you can apply Logic's AutoFilter plugin, which will allow you to cut off a frequency according to various wave shapes, timings, distortions, amounts, and all of this can be broken into x number of EQ bands. I believe it will have the effect you're looking for.

If you want to specifically control the LFO of a synth, pretty much each synth in logic has LFO controls in it. Since you're using Logic Pro X, I'll tell you, definitely start using Alchemy as both a synth and a sampler. You have tremendous filter controls in there and you can start out using it just like EXS24.